# GNU make: run a target after all others, regardless of failures?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with some targets (say `data1` through `dataN`, on which `alldata` depends) that generate some data, and a `prettify` target which iterates over the output and creates a pretty report. (note: there are lots of `dataN` targets and the makefile is machine-generated)

Some of the `dataX` targets occasionally fail, but I would like to run `prettify` anyway, so `prettify` doesn't depend on `alldata`.

Is there a way to run the equivalent of `make -k alldata || make prettify` in a single invocation of make such that make does a best-effort at building all the data, and then builds my report on whatever got made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [prepend the recipes for the dataX targets with a ‘-’](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors),
or you can [list the dataX targets as prerequisites of the special target `.IGNORE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets).

Answer (score 3):

You can write a recursive target with any control logic you like. This doesn't prevent someone from running a target from the command line, so you cannot enforce your logic, but it's nice for a convenience target. Something like this, maybe:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
        $(MAKE) -k -$(MAKEFLAGS) alldata \
        ; rc=$$? \
        ; $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) prettify \
        ; exit $$rc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make normally bails out when a command fails. If you put "|| true" behind the command that fails make will continue to execute, which means your prettify will also be executed.

Comment: Maybe because `-command` does that more succinctly? (I left out the `@` on purpose; it's an antipattern IMHO.)